# How to add padding to the outside of an input in css

Tags: css, input, padding

Everytime I try to add padding around the outside of an input, it just adds padding between the placeholder and the inside of the input.  Does anyone know how to fix this?

```
   #ask {

        padding: 10px  10px 10px 6px;
        font-size:45px;
        background-color:#F2F2F2;
        }


     <input id="ask" type="text" placeholder = "Ex: How tall is the Gateway Arch" autocomplete="on"/>
```

Comment: Why don't you use margin instead?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Padding it's the space between the element and it's content. Maybe you should try margin.

```
#ask {
    margin: 10px  10px 10px 6px;
    font-size:45px;
    background-color:#F2F2F2;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you use margins?
In your case something like that:
margin: 10px  10px 10px 6px;

Padding always clears area around the content of an element.
http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_padding.asp
While margin is used to clear area around an element.
http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_margin.asp

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a `margin` instead of `padding`.

https://jsfiddle.net/Lw4d1ghs/

Margins change the space outside an element, padding change the space within it.

These rules are governed by the CSS **Box Model**: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Introduction_to_the_CSS_box_model

[image: CSS Box Model]